# How to create the return type of a method which returns Task<T> using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, task

We have a class with a number of sync and async methods that return `Response<T>` and `Task<Response<T>>` respectively.

Our program is such that we use reflection to `invoke` the desired method using the `MethodInfo` that reaches to us but before actually invoking the method, a series of checks should be applied and therefore `Error` property of `Response<T>` should be set beforehand (if checks fail) (*codes are just as example*).

```
public class Test
{
    public Response<int> GetAge()
    {
        return new Response<int>() { Error = null, Result = 10 };
    }
    
    public async Task<Response<int>> GetAgeAsync()
    {
        return new Response<int>() { Error = null, Result = 10 };
    }
}

public class Response<T>
{
    public string? Error { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

Creating the return type of sync methods is working fine:

```
public void Execute(MethodInfo? methodInfo, object?[]? parameters) //from: typeof(Test).GetMethod("GetAge");
{
    dynamic response = Activator.CreateInstance(methodInfo.ReturnType);
    
    //some checks...
    
    response.Error = "not allowed.";
    //no need for: methodInfo.Invoke(typeof(Test), parameters);
}
```

but if the return type of method is `Task<T>` (in this example: `Task<Response<int>>`), the `Activator.CreateInstance` complains:

```
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[ConsoleApp.Re
sponse`1[System.Int32]]'.
```

The important point is that we are not allowed to change the return type of methods and we are only allowed to set the value of `Error` property.

Comment: You'll have to special case the logic: if the return type's `.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` is `Task<>`, find the generic type `T` with `.GetGenericArguments`, use that to create the instance and dynamically call out to `Task.FromResult<T>`. (I'm too lazy to write out the code...)

Comment: Are you really sure reflection is the way to go? From your description it sound more like something you could use delegates for.

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with the return type, it's the constructor that is failing.  What do the constructors look like?

Comment: @Neil: they look like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.-ctor). You indeed cannot create a `Task<T>` through `Activator.CreateInstance` and that's not what the code should be attempting to do.

Comment: @JonasH would you please elaborate more? A code snippet maybe.

Comment: If you wanted to wrap an arbitrary method into one that catches exceptions and return a result you could write something like `void CatchException<T>(Func<T> f){try{return new Result<T>{ Result = f()}}catch{return new Result<T>{Error = "failed"}}`  Not sure if that is what you are doing, but reflection is a tool of last resort, so you should not use it if there are better solutions.